# How to know the transaction is active in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, connection

Is there a way to know whether there is any pending transaction in JDBC?
I mean the Connection class method. 
To commit we call

```
Connection con;
con.commit();
```

to rollback

```
con.rollback();
```

But how to know, if the transaction already began. I'm writing multithreaded application, and transaction may began by other process. I must know it.
it may be something like to

```
con.inTransaction();
```

Comment: The documentation for [Transaction.html#isActive()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#isActive%28%29) in Hibernate says "we cannot know that a transaction is active when it is initiated directly through the JDBC Connection", so I'm guessing that the answer to your question is "No."

Comment: why do you need to know it? Should't the other thread release the connection only when it is finished?

Comment: i too don't understand from your question why you need to know when it has started, but if you are worried about your multithreaded environment just say con.autoCommit(false) when you start and set it to true when you are done.

Comment: I already use it. I set autoCommit(false) at the beginning of application. Because all actions are inside of some transaction scope.

Comment: Regarding the above question, I use a singleton to do all database actions therefore the connection is one for all threads. Any way I solved the problem. I defined my own method like startTransaction, where I change the boolean flag, like inTransaction=true, and on my commit() and rollback() methods I set this flag to inTransaction=false.

Comment: Some JDBC drivers (Teradata, Azure Synapse) open a phantom "transaction" for queries and metadata queries, and if you do not call conn.rollback() afterwards, some operations (like drop table) will hang, especially if they are done from a *different* connection.  So it would be nice to know "did the driver leave a transaction open?" so that I can abort it.  Unfortunately I have not discovered how to know that and so we are left to call rollback() quite often.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of

```
con.getAutoCommit()
```

If the return value is 'false' means some one has already disabled autoCommit and they will execute con.commit(). So you can assume that transaction is enabled.